# Xpath for element with different XML structure

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

An element can have two views of XML:

1.

```
<div class="GRUPP_FLG">
    <div role="radiogroup">
        <div class="radioButton">
            <div role="radio" aria-label="Yes">
                <input type="radio">
                <span>Yes</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="radioButton">
            <div role="radio" aria-label="No">
                <input type="radio">
                <span>No</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2.

```
<div class="GRUPP_FLG">
    <div>
        <span title="No" class="readonlyField">
            No
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**In the first case**, I need to click on radiobutton.

```
WebElement radioButton = elementWithRadiogroup.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@aria-label='No']"));
radioButton.click();
```

**In the second case**, I need check that span has a class `readonlyField`

```
if(!elementWithSpan.getAttribute("class").contains("readonlyField"))
    throw new AutotestError("Error");
```

if use

`//div[contains(@class, 'GRUPP_FLG')](//*[@role='radiogroup'] | //span[contains(@class, 'readonlyField')])`

then happens error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the XPath expression 
because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document'
```

How could I get XPath?

Comment: Remove the round bracket s from the xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below `Xpath` this should work for you.

```
//div[contains(@class, 'GRUPP_FLG')]//*[self::*[@role='radiogroup'] | self::span[contains(@class, 'readonlyField')]]
```

**EDIT**:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'GRUPP_FLG')]//*[self::input | self::span[contains(@class, 'readonlyField')]]
```

**Snapshot**:

[image]

Comment: Why for `//div[contains(@class, 'GRUPP_FLG')]//*[self::input | self::span[contains(@class, 'readonlyField')]` may happens error:

`SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 
'//div[contains(@class, 'GRUPP_FLG')]//*[self::input | self::span[contains(@class, 'readonlyField')]' is not a valid XPath expression.` ?

Comment: @NeverSleeps : You have missed the end bracket. I have edited that.Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for your help
alas, the bracket did not help.`"//*[self::input | self::span]"` works, but `//*[self::input | self::span[contains(@class, 'readonlyField')]]` fails

Comment: @NeverSleeps : Strange.When I am using your example I can see three elements are selected.Check the snapshot.

Comment: I swapped elements and it worked. `//*[self::span[contains(@class, 'cpbReadonlyField')] | self::input]`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To validate if the `<span>` has the *class* **`readonlyField`** you can use:

```
try {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='GRUPP_FLG']/div/span[@title='No' and @class='readonlyField']"))
  System.out.println("span has the class readonlyField");
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
  System.out.println("span doesn't have the class readonlyField");
}
```